# Transform appsettings.json in MS Web Deploy Package archive before publishing to IIS (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, webdeploy, appsettings

We're currently migrating a large ASP.NET WebAPI application to ASP.NET Core MVC, which has involved migrating our app setting defaults from a Web.config file into appsettings.json. We'll host on Windows Server using IIS.

In the past we've created a Web Deploy Package, which includes a SetParameters.xml file for customising settings just before deployment (using transforms). This is critical for us as we have many isolated servers hosting the app using different settings.

As far as I'm aware, there's no built-in way to transform the appsettings.json at deployment time, so if using a Web Deploy Package we'd need to manually extract the zip, customize the appsettings.json (or perhaps appsettings.Production.json), then recreate the archive before calling MSDeploy.

This step of indirection is pushing towards publishing to a folder and zipping, then at deploy time extracting the archive, editing the appsettings.json and calling robocopy. One advantage of this method is the extra control over what files are copied, as by default MSDeploy wipes files in the destination directory that don't exist in source (i.e. an added appsettings.*.json or a modified appsettings.json).

This seems like a missing feature in ASP.NET Core with no obvious replacement. Something similar to JSON substitution provided by [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution) would be great. The key point is the transformation needs to be done at deployment time, not at build time. Has anybody else rolled their own solution?

Comment: Ever since i started programming in .NET core (5-6-7) i've been deeply frustrated with how Appsettings and the disconnect with Build Configurations... It seems that every developer and project i've met on my way has had their own hacky way to implement Build Configs.. 

you could do it like this : 
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();